# Get the html content of a svg containing data binding

Tags: angular, svg, binding

I am able to create a svg successfully in my angular component. But when trying to extract the svg html to save it as an img, the template binding values don't appear.

I created the following [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/liRo6UWJjGR3PdUmJsMA?p=preview)
 to demonstrate the issue. when trying to get the `ViewChild outerHtml` the output doesn't contain the inner text nor the x values that are set using the `attr.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`

```
export class App implements OnInit {
  name:string;
  boxTextX:string;
  boxX: string;
  num:string;
  svgContent:string;
  @ViewChild('graph') svg;

  constructor() {
    this.boxX = '45%';
    this.boxTextX = '46%';
    this.num = '46';
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var svgDoc = this.svg.nativeElement;
    this.svgContent = svgDoc.outerHTML;
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/5eBcDyZIAa3q1kcDC7el?p=preview)

Comment: What if I have an input to my component and on change I would like to get the new svgContent. If I try to get the content in ngOnChange, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please update your Plunker to demonstrate what you try to accomplish? I don't really understand your question.

Comment: I updated the plunker. The problem is it's always lagging one on update. Try to enter 2+ digits in the input field, and you will get what I mean.  https://plnkr.co/edit/liRo6UWJjGR3PdUmJsMA?p=preview

Comment: Do you mean `this.boxX = this.num + "%";` which is set after `this.svg.nativeElement.outerHTML` reads the DOM? That's not supposed to work. https://plnkr.co/edit/W8WlWOSc306vK5Nz2sg9?p=preview

Comment: Oh sorry, the order issue was a mistake in the plunker. But it seems like `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` solved the issue. Thanks :)